# Server 12.04 Install

Tags: 12.04, installation, server

I have a Ubuntu Server 12.04 32bit OS that is running both a DNS and a Web sever. I am wanting to add a Mail server to the same tower. Is there a way to do so without a full re-install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean adding mailserver sw to the existing OS? Usually we can do that via tasksel, you can launch it from terminal.

Cheers,

Silvia